# How to grep several pattern at once?

Tags: grep, freebsd

I want to get every line that match there pattern:

- something
- someplace
- somewhere

from /data/rawlog.txt

I try this command, but failed:

```
grep -e "[something|someplace|somewhere]" /data/rawlog.txt
```

Anyone know what goes wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you don't need the brackets. Second, you need extended regular expressions or escape the pipes. One of this should work:

```
egrep -e "something|someplace|somewhere" /data/rawlog.txt
grep -e "something\|someplace\|somewhere" /data/rawlog.txt
```

If you want to place something outside of the fork, don't forget to group it. For example, if you want these patterns to occur only at the end of the line:

```
egrep -e "(something|someplace|somewhere)$" /data/rawlog.txt
```

Note that parenthesis also need egrep or escaping.